# How does Web server handle locking ( await and signal) of request between API calls?

Tags: java, rest, web, java.util.concurrent

We're tasked to implement REST APIs:
1 for holding a request, 1 for releasing the request, and the rest for the in-between processing.

Given that these API calls are on a web server and these are called on separate request, can the signal() match which request is on-hold( await state)?

Please help! There's something I'm not getting here. Thanks in advance!

```
hold(){ 
    hold.await();
}

inBetween(){
    // do some processing
}

release(){
    hold.signal();
}
```

Comment: I think what you're not getting is that what you're describing is not a REST API at all!  It may be an HTTP API of some kind ... but REST is _not_ for APIs where the server holds state - see e.g. [this definition at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Statelessness).  So you need to look into _stateful_ or _session based_ HTTP APIs with your webserver and you'll make more progress.

Comment: Oh ok, but what I want to understand is will something like this work in theory? for example 

1. person A makes a request to hold 
2. person B makes a request to hold 
3. person A makes a request to release

Will it be able to determine which hold it is trying to release?

Comment: You can do this with a _stateful_ or _session based_ web service, by (yourself) taking a lock on whatever object you want to "hold" and tying that to the current session. But it's a dangerous way to go: how long do you hold the lock with everyone else blocked from accessing that item?  What if the user who has the lock never makes the call to release it?  Etc. etc.  Lots of problems in that approach.  It is _much better to not go that route_.  Figure out an API that makes a change to an object in one step, so it _can't_ go wrong if the caller behaves badly (e.g., never makes the second call).

Comment: ... but if you insist on that kind of API then you need to look up _stateful_ or _session based_ web services, not REST services, and you'll find information telling you how to go about it. Search on tag [`[session-state]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-state) or other tags you might find relevant. Or ask a different question.

Comment: Thank you for your response! the idea was supposed to be along the lines of long-polling.